# Enter not working in code (only submit button)

Tags: php, button, input, types, submit

i have following code to make a search on postal code or city:

```
  <input type="text" id="zcc" style="background: #FFF;
  padding: 1px 1px 1px 33px;
  width: 206px;
  height: 28px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;" value="" placeholder="Postcode, Stad" />
    <button id="zccfind" style="cursor: pointer;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   line-height: 14px;
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 16px;
    height: 26px;
    background-color:#57ACD4;
    border: none;
    //  background: url('../image/button.png') repeat-x;-webkit-border-radius:       20px 20px 20px 20px;">Zoek</button>
```

now we need to click the button for the search to activate.
how do i get this to work when pressing enter?

thanks!

Comment: put your full code here...

Comment: Why use `inline` styling, it makes it so much harder to understand. Just use an external stylesheet. Also look in to `JavaScript` `key` events.

Comment: Set the button type to submit. `type="submit"`

Comment: BTW styling in html isn't a good practice

Comment: why on earth are you injecting all that CSS inside a button?!?! Create a CSS class/id and assign it to the button. Plus, where's the relation to PHP here?

Answer (score 0):

i assume you want to capture "enter" key calls on #zcc text input you can use jquery to do that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#zcc').on('keyup', function(e) { //when user presses a button...
   if(e.keyCode == 13) { //if the pressed key is "enter" key
       alert('you submitted form');
     //$("#zccfind").click(); //if you want to submit the button on enter
       return false;
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: `$('#zccfind').click();`? Why not just use the `submit()` function available?

Comment: yeah i thought about this but its not a form its a button thats why i wrote click() i don't know if submit will work

Comment: He wants the ***form*** to submit on enter, so you'd use `submit()` as that's how you submit the form. Clicking the button would be a waste.

Comment: oh okey i am sorry i didn't think about that :) edit: but whats the forms name ? he didn't give enough details

Comment: No problem, just making it clear what the OP wanted.

Comment: You'd just have `$("#yourFormId").submit();` the OP I'm sure would understand that he'd have to change *yourFormId*, also make a note of it in your answer just in case.

Comment: it is on following website: https://autobandenplaats.nl/index.php?route=assembly/assembly  When you search on postal code and click the button it shows below (in a map) the nearest location with markers.... hope this helps a bit

Comment: well your site has no forms so my previews answer worked for it :3

Comment: ok i inserted the code and this works, except it does not follow the submit button. It just pops up with the alert, but it should then behave like the submit button i.e. show the city in the map.... btw i understand this is somewhat without info, but i cannot get all the info here. all the code for this input and the submitting is in one file. I totally understand the inline css but first this needs to be working. the code i have is too long to enter here?